# Transposing a 2D array

Tags: c

I would like to transpose a square matrix, the following is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
void transpose2D(int ar[][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize);
void display(int ar[][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize);
int main()
{
  int ar[SIZE][SIZE], rowSize, colSize;
  int i,j;

  printf("Enter row size of the 2D array: \n");
  scanf("%d", &rowSize);
  printf("Enter column size of the 2D array: \n");
  scanf("%d", &colSize);
  printf("Enter the matrix (%dx%d): \n", rowSize, colSize);
  for (i=0; i<rowSize; i++)
    for (j=0; j<colSize; j++)
      scanf("%d", &ar[i][j]);
  printf("transpose2D(): \n");
  transpose2D(ar, rowSize, colSize);
  display(ar, rowSize, colSize);
  return 0;
}
void display(int ar[][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize)
{
  int l,m;
  for (l = 0; l < rowSize; l++) {
    for (m = 0; m < colSize; m++)
      printf("%d ", ar[l][m]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
void transpose2D(int ar[][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize)
{
  int transpose[rowSize][colSize] ;  
  /* We have to define a new transposed array because otherwise, when some of 
   * the values are changed, it wont be an accurate transposition anymore */ 
  int i , j ; 
  /* This function transposes a given 2D matrix */  
  for (i = 0 ; i < rowSize ; i++) {
    for (j = 0 ; j < colSize ; j++) {
      transpose[j][i] = ar[i][j] ; 
    }
  }
  for (i = 0 ; i < rowSize ; i++) { 
    for (j = 0 ; j < colSize ; j++) {
//   ^^^^    ^^^^   ^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^^  
// edit : assign transpose to ar using for loop 
      ar[i][j] = transpose[i][j] ; 
    }
  }
}
```

Given an input as such,

```
Enter row size of the 2D array: 
4
Enter column size of the 2D array: 
4
Enter the matrix (4x4): 
1 2 3 4
1 1 2 2
3 3 4 4
4 5 6 7
transpose2D(): 
1 2 3 4 
1 1 2 2 
3 3 4 4 
4 5 6 7
```

This is the result that i get. However, what I am supposed to get is

```
transpose2D(): 
1 1 3 4
2 1 3 5
3 2 4 6
4 2 4 7
```

Is there a mistake in my code that I am unable to identify? 
My guess would be that my 2D array transpose[][] is not defined properly, 
but i am unable to point out any mistakes.

Any help is greatly appreciated

edit: 
code above now works with changes highlighted

Comment: Either add a second loop that copies `transpose` back into `ar` or move `transpose` to `main` (e.g. `int transpose[SIZE][SIZE]` -- just like `ar`) and pass a pointer to it (i.e. add another argument to `transpose2D`) and pass the new `transpose` to your print function instead of `ar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `transpose2D`

```
ar[i][j] = transpose[i][j] ;
```

Here you are copying out of bound element of `transpose` to `ar` thats likely to invite undefined behavior

You need to start another loop and copy elements of `transpose` back to `ar`

Comment: Can't believe i did not notice that... Thank you! I will fix it and edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Before we write any code, we should investigate what it is exactly that we should accomplish.

Let's consider a 4×4 array and its transpose. For illustration, I shall use letters A to P to describe the values:

```
A B C D                   A E I M
E F G H   transposed is   B F J N
I J K L                   C G K O
M N O P                   D H L P
```

Note how the diagonal entries, `A`, `F`, `K`, and `P` do not change. Also note how `E` and `B` are swapped; as are `I` and `C`, `J` and `G`, `M` and `D`, and so on.

So, a transpose is, in fact, possible to implement in place, by swapping pairs of elements.

For a 4×4 matrix, there are six pairs to swap:

```
Original                                                   Transpose

A B C D   A E C D   A E I D   A E I M   A E I M   A E I M   A E I M
E F G H   B F G H   B F G H   B F G H   B F J H   B F J N   B F J N
I J K L   I J K L   C J K L   C J K L   C G K L   C G K L   C G K O
M N O P   M N O P   M N O P   D N O P   D N O P   D H O P   D H L P

No swaps    B-E       C-I       D-M       G-J       H-N       L-O
```

Essentially, we swap each one in the lower triangle with the corresponding one in the upper triangle. For illustration, using `L` for lower triangle elements, `U` for upper triangle elements, and `D` for diagonal elements:

```
D U U U
L D U U
L L D U
L L L D
```

We can now write our pseudo-code algorithm:

```
Let T[N][N] be the matrix to be transposed
Let C be the column number in the lower triangular part,
      and the row number in the upper triangular part
Let R be the row number in the lower triangular part
      and the column number in the upper triangular part
For C = 0 to N-1, inclusive:
    For R = C+1 to N-1, inclusive:
        Swap T[C][R] and T[R][C]
    End For
End For
```

The most common error new programmers make, is swap the entry pairs twice. That does two transposes to the same data, which obviously leads to no observable changes, and confuses many a new programmer!